# PHP Sessions issues on different environments

Tags: php, mysql, session, web, localhost

I'm passing the user variable through sessions. It works fine on the localhost but once on the web server it does weird things.

After logging in, the session variable works as should.....until you click on about three pages and it suddenly goes POOF!

Notice the "`Welcome, jordan.`" as opposed to the "`Welcome, .`" Also the top left corner.

Session functioning: 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/32/loggedins.png/

Session POOF!
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/515/loggedinno.png/

Login/Create session variable code:

```
<?php
        include_once 'gtheader.php';
        if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
        if (isset($_POST['user']))
        {
        $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
        $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
        if (preg_match($txtMatch,$user))
        {
        if ($user == "" || $pass == "")
        {
        $error = "Please enter all required fields";
        }
        else
        {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gtmembers WHERE user='$user'";
        $result = queryMysql($query);
        $rank = mysql_result($result, 0, 'rank');
        if (!mysql_num_rows($result))
        {
        $error = "Username does not exist.";
        }
        else
        {
        $getPass = mysql_result($result, 0, 'pass');
        $salt = substr($getPass, 0, 64);
        $hash = $salt . $pass;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) 
        {
        $hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
        }
        $hash = $salt . $hash;
        if ($hash == $getPass)
        {
        if ($rank != "Banned")
        {
        $userLow = strtolower($user);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $userLow;
        $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
        echo <<<_END
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href='index.php';
        </script>
        _END;
        echo "Successfully logged in. Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to continue.";
        }
```

Header Code:

```
        <?php //gtheader.php
        session_start();
        include_once 'gtfunctions.php';
        $loggedIn = FALSE;

        if (isset($_SESSION['user']))
        {
        $user = $_SESSION['user'];
        if ($user) echo "Current User: $user<br />";
        else echo "Current User: None<br />";
        $rank = $_SESSION['rank'];
        $loggedIn = TRUE;
        echo "is set SESSION['user']? Yes";
        }
        else echo "is set SESSION['user']? No";

        echo "<div id='header'><a class='header' href='index.php'> <h1 id='headerTitle'>$appname</h1></a>";
        if ($loggedIn == TRUE)
        {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM gtmessages WHERE recip='$user' AND status='0'";
        $result = queryMysql($query);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) $num = "";
        else $num = "[".mysql_num_rows($result)."]";
        if ($rank == 'Owner' || $rank == 'Admin')
        {
        echo "Welcome, <a class='header' href='gtmembers.php?view=$user'>$user</a><a     class='header' href='gtmessage.php'>$num</a>. [<a class='header'     href='gtlogout.php'>Logout</a>] | <a class='header' href='gtadmin.php'>Admin</a><br />";
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Welcome, <a class='header' href='gtmembers.php?view=$user'>$user</a><a     class='header' href='gtmessage.php'>$num</a>. [<a class='header'     href='gtlogout.php'>Logout</a>]<br />";
        }
        }
?>
```

Comment: Is there any chance it could be hostgator? This code worked with 1&1

Comment: in header file check session by print_r($_SESSION), so you can see all values are coming or not..

Comment: what is the php version on your machine and the other server?

Answer (score 1):

*isset()* will return true for an array even if the array is empty.

You should use *!empty()* instead.

**Update**
Also make sure that the servers are configured to store variables the same way.

**Update 2**

```
    <?php
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors", 1); 
    include_once 'gtheader.php';
    if (empty($_SESSION['user'])){
        if (!empty($_POST['user'])){
            $user = sanitizeString($_POST['user']);
            $pass = sanitizeString($_POST['pass']);
            if (preg_match($txtMatch,$user)){
                if (empty($user) || empty($pass)){
                    $error = "Please enter all required fields";
                }else{
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM gtmembers WHERE user='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'";
                    $result = queryMysql($query);
                    $rank = mysql_result($result, 0, 'rank');
                }
            }
            if (!mysql_num_rows($result)){
                $error = "Username does not exist.";
            }else{
                $getPass = mysql_result($result, 0, 'pass');
                $salt = substr($getPass, 0, 64);
                $hash = $salt . $pass;
                for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++){
                    $hash = hash('sha256', $hash);
                }
                $hash = $salt . $hash;
                if ($hash == $getPass){
                    if ($rank !== "Banned"){
                        $userLow = strtolower($user);
                        $_SESSION['user'] = $userLow;
                        $_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
                        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
                        echo "Successfully logged in. Click <a href='index.php'>here</a> to continue.";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

gtheader.php

```
    <?php //gtheader.php
    session_start();
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors", 1); 

            include_once 'gtfunctions.php';
            $loggedIn = FALSE;

            if(session_id() == "")
            {   session_start(); } 

            if(empty($_REQUEST['PHPSESSID'])){
                $session_id = session_id();
            } else {
                $session_id = $_REQUEST['PHPSESSID'];   
            }

            if (!empty($_SESSION['user'])){

                //This is not safe at all. Someone could change the user to %
                $user = $_SESSION['user'];

                    echo "Current User: $user<br />";
                //This is not safe either. Someone could change their rank to Admin.
                $rank = $_SESSION['rank'];

                $loggedIn = TRUE;
                echo "is set SESSION['user']? Yes";
            } else {
             $user = '';
             $rank = '';
             echo "is set SESSION['user']? No";
            }

            echo "<div id='header'><a class='header' href='index.php'> <h1 id='headerTitle'>$appname</h1></a>";
            if ($loggedIn == TRUE){
            //without filtering, someone could set the user to % which would return everyone from the DB.       
            $query = "SELECT * FROM gtmessages WHERE recip='".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."' AND status='0'";
            //This is not a standard function so we're assuming it's set in gtfunctions.php
            $result = queryMysql($query);
            //Here you're only checking if this is set, not how many
            if (empty(mysql_num_rows($result))){
                 $num = "";} else {
                     //If they trick your SQL statement into returning more than one...
                     $num = "[".mysql_num_rows($result)."]";
                 }
            if ($rank == 'Owner' || $rank == 'Admin')
            {
            echo "Welcome, <a class='header' href='gtmembers.php?view=$user'>$user</a><a class='header' href='gtmessage.php'>$num</a>. [<a class='header' href='gtlogout.php'>Logout</a>] | <a class='header' href='gtadmin.php'>Admin</a><br />";
            } else {
            echo "Welcome, <a class='header' href='gtmembers.php?view=$user'>$user</a><a     class='header' href='gtmessage.php'>$num</a>. [<a class='header'     href='gtlogout.php'>Logout</a>]<br />";
            }
       }
    ?>
```

You'll want to use something like Firebug in Firefox in order to check the headers and see if it's passing a cookie to you for the session or if the sessions are being stored serverside only. Also if the sessions are passed via the GET variables.

There is a lot of blind trusting of the user provided info (like sessions). Someone could hijack a session or spoof a higher username or rank. There is no check in the code to see if the user rank is set correctly.

I cleaned up a bit of the SQL stuff under gtheader. Again there is blind trusting in the stuff being passed straight to SQL. If the SQL user doing the query has write access to the tables then you could have a potential for an injection attack.

Comment: Even still, that doesnt account for why the session array keeps emptying.